# Showing tab bar with javascript in Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I am able to hide tab bar when I am pushing a new page. but while coming back to main screen, I am not able to show tab bar again with script if i press device back button.

Please help. Following is the code :

```
 module.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.incremental = 0;  
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    function onBackKeyDown() {
        // Handle the back button
        if ($rootScope.home.getPages().length > 1) {
            $rootScope.hide = 'false';
            $rootScope.home.popPage();
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
                $rootScope.incremental++;

                if($rootScope.incremental == 1){
                    ons.notification.confirm({
                        message: 'Are you sure you want to exit?',
                        title: 'Exit App?',
                        buttonLabels: ['Yes', 'No'],
                        cancelable: true,
                        callback: function(index) {
                            if(index == 0){
                                navigator.app.exitApp();    
                            } else {
                                $rootScope.incremental = 0;
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }                        
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
    }

});

<ons-tabbar animation="fade" hide-tabs="{{$root.hide}}">
        <ons-tab active="true" page="index.html">
            <div class="tab">
                <ons-icon icon="ion-home" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                <div class="tab-label">Home</div>
            </div>
        </ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="about.html">
            <div class="tab">
                <ons-icon icon="ion-information-circled" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                <div class="tab-label">About App</div>
            </div>
        </ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

in the corresponding controller you can show it again right ? just you have to add show it again inside the controller and outside the function. When you click the function it will again hide. when you come back it will show